# Records are not fetching date wise in SQL Server. 0 records found

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to get the records from Dec-1-2019 to Dec-31-2019 but I am not getting any records from the database while checking with out date filter the records are coming. There are records in the database table between these days but not coming.

Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA 
WHERE DEVICEID = '786423' 
  AND DeviceTimeStamp BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '12/1/2019 12:00:00 AM', 103)  
                          AND CONVERT(DATE, '1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM', 103) 
ORDER BY DeviceTimeStamp ASC
```

Sample data

```
2019-12-03 11:53:25.000 944.5
2019-12-03 11:38:07.000 944.5
2019-12-03 11:22:59.000 944.2
2019-12-03 11:07:09.000 943.9
```

C# Code

```
fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrm.Text); 12/1/2019 12:00:00 AM
todate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTo.Text);

datatype - datetime, null
```

Comment: You did not tag any development language but you posted csharp code. So if the issue is related to csharp code in your application, then post that code. After that, **READ** the documentation about convert. What does style 103 mean? It means dd/mm/yyyy. So your tsql logic is searching for values between Jan 12 2019 and Jan 1 2020 which does not match your goal. Is that what you mean by "not coming"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider specifying an ISO 8601 datetime literal. That will be independent of the session `DATEFORMAT` setting and eliminate the need for `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA
WHERE
DEVICEID='786423'
AND DeviceTimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-12-01T00:00:00'
AND '2020-01-01T00:00:00' ORDER BY DeviceTimeStamp;
```

You might also consider specifying an inclusive start date and exclusive end date:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA 
WHERE
DEVICEID='786423'
AND DeviceTimeStamp >= '2019-12-01T00:00:00'
AND DeviceTimeStamp < '2020-01-01T00:00:00'
ORDER BY DeviceTimeStamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select CONVERT(date,'12/1/2019 12:00:00 AM',103), CONVERT(date,'1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM',103)
```

```
(No column name)    | (No column name)   
:------------------ | :------------------
12/01/2019 00:00:00 | 01/01/2020 00:00:00
```

You can see that you are not using the proper date format: `CONVERT(date,'12/1/2019 12:00:00 AM',103)` should be `CONVERT(date,'1/12/2019 12:00:00 AM',103)`. However this should not prevent you from getting results (since you actually end up with an date range that is much larger than you intended). Possibly, the other condition in the `WHERE` clause is restricting the matches.

I would, anyway, recommend using the following syntax:

```
DeviceTimeStamp >=  CAST('2019-12-01' as DATE) 
AND DeviceTimeStamp <  CAST('2020-01-01' as DATE)
```

Because:

- this relies on explicit casting and standard date format
- this uses the half-open strategy to check for date ranges; with your existing `BETWEEN` condition, a record with date `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'` would be allowed, while this is most likely not what you want